# If my father doesn't study the Veda, does this make me ineligible to learn Vedas?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, manu-smriti, shudra

Manusmriti 2.168

> योऽनधीत्य द्विजो वेदमन्यत्र कुरुते श्रमम् । 
>   स जीवन्नेव शूद्रत्वमाशु गच्छति सान्वयः ॥
>
> The twice-born man, who, not having learnt the Veda, labors over other
>   things, soon falls, along with his descendants, even while living, to
>   the state of the śūdra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the father is not learned in the Vedas, even then the son is allowed to study them.

> Manu Smriti 3.136. **If there is a father ignorant of the sacred texts
>   whose son has learned one whole recension of the Veda** and the Angas,
>   and a son ignorant of the sacred texts whose father knows an entire
>   recension of the Veda and the Angas,
>
> Manu Smriti 3.137. Know that he whose father knows the Veda, is the
>   more venerable one (of the two); **yet the other one is worthy of
>   honour**, because respect is due to the Veda (which he has learned).

In 3.137, the **other one** refers to the son who is learned in the Vedas but whose father is not. Now, even such a son is worthy of respect.

So, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 2):

This Shloka has nothing to do with studying of Vedas by father or son, it's wrongly interpreted above, read this:

> योऽनधीत्य द्विजो वेदमन्यत्र कुरुते श्रमम् ।
>
> स जीवन्नेव शूद्रत्वमाशु गच्छति सान्वयः ॥ मनुस्मृति । २ । १६८ ॥
>
> मनु स्मृति के दूसरे अध्याय के १६८ वें श्लोक के अनुसार जिस द्विज
>   ब्राह्मण ने वेद व वेदांग शास्त्र के अध्ययन के बदले धर्म निरपेक्ष व
>   धर्म हीन शिक्षा ग्रहण की है वह ब्राह्मण से च्युत होकर अपने ही जीवन काल
>   में , अपने वंश सहित, शूद्र वर्ण को प्राप्त करता है।
>
> According to Manu Smriti: The twice born Brahmin who instead of studying Vedas
>   and Ved Shastras, studies profane or faithless material, then that
>   Brahmin (along with his descendents) in the present life cycle falls
>   to the state of the śūdra.

read more [here](https://www.shrinathdham.com/resources/shri-shuk-prashaadi/shudra-hindi.html) I think we should not always go by the way things have been translated in english.

Some what similar meaning [here](http://aryamantavya.in/heen-karmon-se-varn-parivartan/):

> ३) योऽनधीत्य द्विजो वेदमन्यत्र कुरुते श्रमम् | स जीवन्नेव शुद्रत्वमाशु
>   गच्छति सान्वय: || (मनुस्मृति २/१६८)
>
> अर्थ-जो द्विज अर्थात् ब्राह्मण, क्षत्रिय, वैश्य वेदाध्ययन का त्याग कर
>   अन्य विद्याओं में ही परिश्रम करता रहता है, वह जीते-जी अपने आश्रित
>   परिजनों के सहित शूद्रता को प्राप्त हो जाता है। क्योंकि, उसका
>   ब्राह्मणत्व प्रदान करने वाला वेदाध्ययन छूटने से उसके आश्रित परिजनों का
>   भी छूट जाता है, अतः वह परिवार शूद्र कहलाता है।
>
> Means: The twice born Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaishaya who gives up
>   studying Vedas and continues to labour in other fields, then that
>   person (along with his descendents) in the present life cycle falls to
>   the state of the śūdra. hence such a family is referred as śūdra
>   parivaar (family)

Comment: You should translate what you quoted into English, since this is an English language site.

Comment: This is an English language site and most of the users can't understand Hindi. So, please translate the text into English otherwise the answer may be deleted.